# cut and paste a image file and upload it on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file-upload, copy-paste

I have code whereby I cut and paste an image in a `div` and it will upload the the image and store the file in a directory. I tried to change my code to upload the cut and paste file data on submit.

`readastext` seems to store the data in the hidden field. it also transfers the data on submit to the php file processor but no file is being created in the target directory. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pasteTarget').on('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.originalEvent;
    
    if (data.clipboardData && data.clipboardData.items) {
      var items = data.clipboardData.items;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
          var file = items[i].getAsFile();
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function() {
            $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "file[]").appendTo("form").val(reader.result);
          };
          reader.readAsText(file);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  
  $('#subfile').on('click', function(e) {
    var form = $('form')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'postfileuploader.php',
      data: data,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: grey" id="pasteTarget">
    Click and paste here.
  </div>
  <button type="button" name="sub" id="subfile" class="btn btn-primary">Create Tasks</button>
</form>
```

this is the postfileuploader.php

```
 <?php

echo $fileName = $_FILES['file'][0]['name'];
echo $fileType = $_FILES['file'][0]['type'];
echo $fileError = $_FILES['file'][0]['error'];
?>
```

> this gives me an error  Notice: Undefined index: file in
> F:\xampp745\htdocs\xxx\postfileuploader.php on line

an print_r($_POST) gives me

> Array (
> [file] => Array
> (
> [0] =>file information code

Comment: If the JS succeeds, things go wrong at the server. We need to see the server-side code which tries to create the file.

Comment: @Teemu code added - i was wondering should i store the file data as a blob in the  hidden field before it is submittedrather than a text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileReader.readAsText()` reads the file as a plain text string. You should use `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` so the image data can be included as a value in the form. You can read more here: [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: seems to work what i get is if I do a print_r($_POST)  is Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [0] => data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QEZRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABQEAAAMAAAABBDgAAAEBAAMAAAABCSQAAAExAA .... is this how do i go about converting or storing this into an image file ? ???

Comment: @Apurva You need to decode base64 in php and write to file. This will be helpful: [base64 to image](https://netcell.netlify.app/blog/2016/04/image-base64). If this doesn't work for you I can make a function to do it.

Comment: yup got it... thanks